# Python/RegEx/findall: How do I extract a pattern from behind the match?

Tags: python, regex

I did look into lookbehind pattern (?<=...) but this doesn't seem to save the match.

input:

```
aaaaaaGET(abc)aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaMATCH(00)aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaGEX(xyz)aaaaaa
aaaaaaGET(notneed)aaaaaa
aaaaaaGEX(no)aaaaaa
aaaaaaGET(nope)aaaaaa
aaaaaaGET(AbC)aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaMATCH(01)aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaGEX(XYz)aaaaaa
```

output:

```
[(abc, 00, xyz), (AbC, 01, XYz]
```

I want use `re.findall` to find all the MATCH parts, and then what follows both GET (above the match) and GEX (below the match), but I can't figure out how to get anything like that from behind.

If all my related matches were ahead of MATCH, I'd have something like

```
re.findall('MATCH\((\d*)\).*?GEX\(([A-Za-z]*)\)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

But not sure how to get back and get the GET value

Comment: Did you forget to include the actual pattern used by you? Also, what is `GETX`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't really have one. I just added how I'd get the match if it was only one way if this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """aaaaaaGET(abc)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaaaaaaaa
... aaaaaMATCH(00)aaaaaaa
... aaaaaaaaaaaaa
... aaaaGEX(xyz)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaGET(notneed)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaGEX(no)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaGET(nope)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaGET(AbC)aaaaaa
... aaaaaaaaaaaaa
... aaaaaaaaaaaaa
... aaaaaMATCH(01)aaaaaaa
... aaaaaaaaaaaaa
... aaaaGEX(XYz)aaaaaa"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'GET.*?\(([^)]*)\)(?:(?!GET|GEX).)*?\(([^)]*)\)(?:(?!GET|GEX).)*?GEX\(([^)]*)\)', s, re.DOTALL)
>>> m
[('abc', '00', 'xyz'), ('AbC', '01', 'XYz')]
```

`(?:(?!GET|GEX).)*` negative lookahead checks for following  three characters not to be `GET` or `GEX`, if it is not present, then only it matches the next character.